# apps script to change item type in a form

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that I can change item properties, but I can't seem to figure out how to change the item type.  For example I want to change it from a text field type to a list field type.  I know that I can delete and item and create a new one but that doesn't solve my problem because I want to be able to make this change after a workflow is being used and there is data already submitted thru the form.  Does anyone know of a way to do this?